# Left join table to un-scramble address table

Tags: sql

Our customer address database became corrupt during sorting/processing.  I need to query the customer's original list against our corrupted list to find the original information.

"Original_list" (in the code below, original list is called "ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN) contains roughly 85000 entries, most of which are totally worthless.
Basic format of table:
Name, Post_Addr1, Post_Addr2, Post_City, Post_State, Post_Zip, Phy_Addr1, Phy_Add2, Phy_City, Phy_State, Phy_Zip

This table has every customer's name.  It has customer's name in either Post_add format, Phy_add format, or both.

"Corrupted_list" (in the code below, corrupted list is called "aspen_scrubbed_but_wrong_list) has about 35000 entries, including the Street Addresses I need for final output, but their associated Name, City, State, Zipcode information have been scrambled up.

Format of table:
Fullname, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zipcode

I need to use the Street Address from "Corrupted_List" and Street address from "Original_list" as keys, and output the associated Name, City, State, Zipcode from the Original_list.

Problem 2: "original_list" has the two differently named sets of 'address' columns.  Can I make the query search for results that check corrupt_list.DELADDR against original_list.postal_address1 AND original_list.physical_address1?

THANK YOU THANK YOU in advance for all input!

```
SELECT aspen_scrubbed_but_wrong_list.DELADDR, 
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.FullName, 
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.physical_address1, 
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.physical_address2, 
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.physical_city, ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.physical_state,
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.physical_postcode, 
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.postal_address1,
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.postal_address2, ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.postal_city,
ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.postal_state, ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.postal_postcode

FROM aspen_scrubbed_but_wrong_list
LEFT JOIN ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN ON aspen_scrubbed_but_wrong_list.DELADDR=ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.physical_address1'
```

My output isn't giving me:
Address (corrupted_list), Name (original_list), City (original_list), State (original_list), Zipcode (original_list).  I'm pretty newb at SQL.

Edit:
I think this is what Strawberry was asking for (MCRE):

The output I'd hope for would look like:
Peyton Otis, 0863 Temperance Point Pl, Westerville, OH, 43082
Catherine Fabian, 0207 Fechko House, Columbus, OH, 43210

[Data samples -- left of black bar is Corrupt_list, right of black bar is Original_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6gFm.png)

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags (mysql and sqlite) and added sql instead.

Answer (score 0):

With a `LEFT JOIN` you will end up with rows consisting of `DELADDR` followed by a bunch of `NULL` columns, if `DELADDR` is not present in `ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN`, if you only want to get the addresses that match, you can use `JOIN` instead.

Other than that, if you change your join condition to 
`ON aspen_scrubbed_but_wrong_list.DELADDR=ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.physical_address1 OR aspen_scrubbed_but_wrong_list.DELADDR=ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN.postal_address1` it should achieve the desired result

(You may need to remove for duplicates using `DISTINCT`, if for example a row in `ASBCO_LIST_TO_CLEAN` has the sames value in both address columns

**Edit:** if you want BOTH columns to match with `DELADDR`, then replace the `OR` above by `AND` :)